# How to inject @Repository and multiple @Services into Spring testing context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing

I'm working on a REST endpoint using Spring and I'd like to test the business logic separately in a way when it includes the mapper, repository and validation logics. They are not mocked. It is a fat integration test (if this definition exists) or a system test but the REST part is not included.

Why not mocking? I don't like them, they don't really provide any value since I define their behavior and that definition does not reflect on the code I want to test. It can be as buggy as the code I wrote. :) For me the value is when I can test the whole stack or big portion of the stack in build time, and fast. I rather manipulate the inputs to trigger behaviors and leave the mocks for behaviors cannot be triggered by inputs (do thsey make any sense?).

The problem I face is how to wire these together in a test? All the examples and articles I have found so far are 1, `@DataJpaTest` which focuses only the repository, 2, Controller or system tests with mocked underlying logic.

What I need is the ability to test my small libraries in a the combination (either have them mocked, not mocked or some of them mocked and some of them not) I see valuable.

Based on the articles I read so far the problem is that during testing Spring loads just a slice of the context and I need to load what I need to be there. I haven't found that how can I load into the test context what I need.

```java
public class IAMBusinessLogicImplementation implements IAMBusinessLogicInterface {

    private final UserRepositoryInterface _userRepository;
    private final UserMapperInterface _userMappers;
    private final IAMValidatorInterface _validator;

    public IAMBusinessLogicImplementation(
        @NonNull UserRepositoryInterface _userRepository,
        @NonNull UserMapperInterface _userMappers,
        @NonNull IAMValidatorInterface _validator) {
        this._userRepository = _userRepository;
        this._userMappers = _userMappers;
        this._validator = _validator;
    }

    public UserDto createUser(@NonNull UserDto userDto) {
        // stuff
    }
}

public class IAMValidatorImplementation implements IAMValidatorInterface { }

public class UserMapperImplementation implements UserMapperInterface { }

public interface UserRepositoryInterface extends CrudRepository<User, Long> { }
```

Test:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = {IAMBusinessLogicImplementation.class})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.encyclopediagalactica.iam.tests.repository")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@AutoConfigureDataJpa
@EntityScan("com.encyclopediagalactica.iam.entities")
@ComponentScan()
public class IAMBusinessLogicTestsBase {

    @Autowired
    public IAMBusinessLogicInterface _sut;

    @Test
    public void createUser() {
        // Arrange
        UserDto userDto = UserDto.builder()
            .firstName("asd")
            .lastName("dsa")
            .build();

        // Act
        UserDto result = _sut.createUser(userDto);

        // Assert
        assertThat(result).isNotNull();
    }

}
```

Result:

> 2023-04-23T21:28:24.598+02:00  INFO 37577 --- [           main]
> c.e.i.t.b.IAMBusinessLogicTestsBase      : Starting
> IAMBusinessLogicTestsBase using Java 17.0.7 with PID 37577 (started by
> andrascsanyi in
> /Users/andrascsanyi/DEV/github.com/EncyclopediaGalactica/IAM/IAM)
> 2023-04-23T21:28:24.601+02:00  INFO 37577 --- [           main]
> c.e.i.t.b.IAMBusinessLogicTestsBase      : No active profile set,
> falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
> 2023-04-23T21:28:24.739+02:00  INFO 37577 --- [           main]
> .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data
> JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode. 2023-04-23T21:28:24.759+02:00  INFO
> 37577 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate :
> Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 8 ms. Found 0 JPA
> repository interfaces. 2023-04-23T21:28:24.899+02:00  INFO 37577 --- [
> main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing
> PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default] 2023-04-23T21:28:24.919+02:00
> INFO 37577 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version
> : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
> 2023-04-23T21:28:25.049+02:00  INFO 37577 --- [           main]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
> 2023-04-23T21:28:25.137+02:00  INFO 37577 --- [           main]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added
> connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testing user=SA
> 2023-04-23T21:28:25.138+02:00  INFO 37577 --- [           main]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start
> completed. 2023-04-23T21:28:25.147+02:00  INFO 37577 --- [
> main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using
> dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect 2023-04-23T21:28:25.489+02:00
> INFO 37577 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator
> : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation:
> [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
> 2023-04-23T21:28:25.492+02:00  INFO 37577 --- [           main]
> j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA
> EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
> 2023-04-23T21:28:25.495+02:00  WARN 37577 --- [           main]
> o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'IAMBusinessLogicImplementation':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'com.encyclopediagalactica.iam.repositories.UserRepositoryInterface'
> available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
> candidate. Dependency annotations: {} 2023-04-23T21:28:25.495+02:00
> INFO 37577 --- [           main]
> j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA
> EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
> 2023-04-23T21:28:25.495+02:00  INFO 37577 --- [           main]
> .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed
> evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
> 2023-04-23T21:28:25.497+02:00  INFO 37577 --- [           main]
> com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown
> initiated... 2023-04-23T21:28:25.498+02:00  INFO 37577 --- [
> main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 -
> Shutdown completed. 2023-04-23T21:28:25.500+02:00  INFO 37577 --- [
> main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation
> report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
> 2023-04-23T21:28:25.508+02:00 ERROR 37577 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

Comment: Either load the full context using `@SpringBootTest` (and you base test tries to much) or provide a specific `@TestConfiguration` to supply what you need.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks! You saved my 4ss! If you write an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to outsmart Spring Boot and its loading mechanisms. Don't do that as you should be working with the framework.

You have 2 options here.

1. Use a single `@SpringBootTest` and load the full context (maybe with some mocked services, or in-memory database implementations).
2. Use a dedicated and specific `@TestConfiguration` to load exactly what you need.

I strongly suggest option 1. as option 2 will get quite tedious and will probably lead to longer test times (as there is no reuse of a previously loaded context).

Comment: Indeed this was the problem. A `@SpringBootTest` with a `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)` solved the problem. I overcomplicated the whole. Thanks for the help.